# I have two regex in .net preRegex = "(?<=(^|[^A-Za-z0-9]+))" postRegex = "(?=([^A-Za-z0-9]+)|$)" . What is the alternate of it in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two regex strings in .net

```
preRegex = "(?<=(^|[^A-Za-z0-9]+))"
postRegex = "(?=([^A-Za-z0-9]+)|$)"
```

I want their alternative in python. My problem is let say I have a string

```
s="I am in aeroplane."
```

What I need is to replace "aeroplane with aeroPlain" so I want to make regex like

```
newKey = preRegex + aeroplane + postRegex
pattern = re.compile(newKey,re.IGNORECASE)
```

new regex string look like

```
(?<=(^|[^A-Za-z0-9]+))aeroplane(?=([^A-Za-z0-9]+)|$)
```

but it is giving me error "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern".
I am new to python, Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As the question stands, I'm not sure what the objective is. It may be helpful to include .NET code that has the working regular expression. It may also be helpful to include the generalized objective. E.g. "looking to replace all instances of aeroplane with aeroPlain in a string".

Comment: The error is crystal clear: `Python lookbehind assertions need to be fixed width`, on top of this in your current example your pattern is at the end of the string so you could replace it by `(?=\.|$)`

Comment: How to handle this situation? when i have not fixed width?

Comment: Correct is `preRegex = "(?<![A-Za-z0-9])"` and `postRegex = "(?![A-Za-z0-9])"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(^|[^A-Za-z0-9]+)aeroplane([^A-Za-z0-9]+|$)
```

and when you replace, you can call the **back reference** to the first and second part of your regex to fetch their value.

Replacement string will be something like `'\1aeroPlain\2'`.
For more information on backref in python:https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is not quite right since what you suggest won't work exactly the same in case of overlapping matches.

Comment: could you develop a bit more? Sensei :-)